# How to avoid being like a Fake web site

Tags: website-design, interface

I am doing website for monitoring tool and Site Main Page looks like a bit Fake because of the 5 options on left side.

[image: Here is the main page]

What should i change on the website to avoid that?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "Fake", but you could start by spelling "Standard" correctly in the first bullet point, and correcting the broken english in the title: "in a Seconds"

Comment: john true asking how not to be fake. There is an air of irony about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is phrased a bit awkwardly, but it does raise a good point: how do you build credibility (and therefore trust) on a website?

[According to Nielsen:](https://www.nngroup.com/reports/ecommerce-ux-trust-and-credibility/)

> Trust is essential to the user's willingness to risk time, money, and personal data on a website. If you lose trust, you lose the sale and you may lose the customer as well.

There's a few things to consider here:

- Design Quality
- Upfront Disclosure
- Social proof

[People appreciate when sites are upfront with all information that relates to the customer experience.](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/trustworthy-design/) This includes details such as prominently displaying contact information, documenting what is included in a base cost, stating any additional fees or charges that may accompany a service, presenting links to the return policy and guarantees, or revealing shipping charges before asking for billing information. When sites omit basic information, they will raise flags with the user. What are they hiding? Can I trust them if they do this? Being transparent about your service and/or products shows that you understand your customers, and that will reflect in more credibility. People want to know who they are doing business with. Tell them.

In the same vein, people are also looking for external sources that tell them everything is alright. They look for **social proof**.

> Several participants in our study commented that while they do research online for various services, they are distrustful of sites or services that weren’t recommended by friends or family or at least other people on the web — regardless of how beautiful the website may be. One participant explained, “Whenever I choose a company to work with, I make sure I know them well. So it has to be a company [that I can see others use]. It would be good if they have customer reviews, maybe a media [press release].”

Users are looking for external opinions, think: user reviews, testimonials, awards, authority labels (like certificates for safe shopping) etc.

[Graphic design is the glue that holds all these factors together.](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/trustworthy-design/) The standard for what is considered a well-designed site constantly shifts in response to trends that eventually become the norm. A website that appears outdated, contains lots of typos, takes too long to load, or tries to cram too much content in a small amount of space, raises red flags for a user.

---

Specifically for your website; make sure you're building up a story on why your software is good at what it does. Show short snippets with features and issues it solves, show user quotes, show logo's of your established users. You need to show people which issues your software fixes, not just a list features.